# Trouble with webscraping using string methods in Python

Tags: python, html, urllib

I'm extremely new to web scraping and I'm making a simple program with Python which uses string methods such as `str.find()`.

Currently, I extract the HTML code of a webpage as a string via

```
from urllib.request import urlopen

html_str = urlopen(url).read().decode('utf-8')
```

However, I am confused as to why all of the code isn't returned. For example, a Youtube channel page displays the subscriber count with

```
<yt-formatted-string id="subscriber-count" class="style-scope ytd-c4-tabbed-header-renderer">106M subscribers</yt-formatted-string>
```

But this string does not appear in `html_str`.

So, what's going wrong? Is there anything that I am doing or using incorrectly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some of the web scraping libraries do not fetch JavaScript code or values. One library that I do know that does fetch JavaScript code as well is "Selenium". But it comes at the cost that it will run seemingly slower than other scraping libraries.